# Move a cell based on date input across row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have multiple people with a single task that they have to complete on a certain date. I need to put each person into their own row and have dates in the title of each column. I want each person's task for the day to correspond to the dates in the title. I could manually put them in, but this is very tedious when I have several people to schedule for.

I want to be able to input a date on a separate sheet and have excel place the task on the schedule automatically. Here's an example of what I want:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Note: I have no experience with VBA, and if this is an easy fix with it, then I apologize and I would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial on Excel formulas? Or to hire someone to create an Excel spreadsheet for you? Or do you have a specific problem getting `=vlookup()` to work for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) explains how to use the `=vlookup()` formula to reference a cell based on another cell and a value.

The syntax is as follows:

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

If `B1` contains the date you care about and `A2` contains the employee ID, you might use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B$1, INDIRECT($A2&"!A:B"), 2, FALSE)
```

Each employee would need their own worksheet with a name matching the contents of cell `A2`, etc. Those worksheets would be formatted with column `A` containing dates and column `B` containing tasks.